# Wireframe looks pixelated after applying a shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

How the basic geometry looks like without a shader:

[image]

How it looks like with the shader:

[image]

I'm trying to apply a Bokeh shader, using the code from this [example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_dof.html) and I would like only the back side of the geometry to be blurry.
**Any ideas why the wireframe looks so weird/fuzzy?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the pixel ratio wasn't set correctly in the EffectComposer.